# How to manage 3rd-party library in iOS project if its source code needs to be modified in order to be used?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

We need to use some 3rd-party libraries in our iOS app project (which is an `Xcode` project).  The 3rd-party libraries are either managed by `Cocoapods` or directly added in the project by importing source code files.

Sometimes we need to modify a library's source code in order to actually use it appropriately in our project.  It's easy to make the modification since we have all the source code at our hand, but how can we maintain the modification when some time in the future we upgrade the version of the 3rd-party library?  Is there any tools or best practice out there that can help with this?  And after the upgrade of the 3rd-party library, it will be good if we could differentiate in the code history about which part is done by library upgrade and which part is done by our modification.

Comment: if you use Git ,I think it will catch it and tell you what is the deferent you can see where is your modify. unless they delete that file. But also you can check there git and see what this new v. contain.

Answer (score 0):

That depends entirely on what your change is...

The best option is to not change the external code. Instead, subclass the part you need to change and use only public API so you should find out early when updating if the subclass needs to change. Unit tests also help.

If you can't subclass then you should fork the external code, then you have to manually merge updates on top of your change when you want them. This is obviously significantly more effort both in terms of importing and managing the code.